# How to load my custom Session ID generator with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

Does Tomcat have any configurations which can load my custom session id generator(replace the default StandardSessionIdGenerator) easily without change the source code of the Tomcat?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you implemented your own session id generator. Is there something that Tomcat isn't doing that you'd really like it to do?

Comment: I need my session id being used the full character set of alpha numeric instead of hex rendered string that tomcat default implementation.

Comment: Why? You need shorter session ids with the same strength?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is where you find all the details](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/sessionidgenerator.html):

Configure server.xml according to the linked documentation:

> The `SessionIdGenerator` element represents the session id generator
>   that will be used to create session ids used by web application HTTP
>   sessions.
>
> A `SessionIdGenerator` element MAY be nested inside a `Manager` component.
>   If it is not included, a default SessionIdGenerator configuration will
>   be created automatically, which is sufficient for most requirements, —
>   see Standard SessionIdGenerator Implementation below for the details
>   of this configuration.
>
> ...

The documentation continues with the standard attributes that any session id generator should support. Key for you is `className` (actually, that's tomcat-supported to look up your class), then there are `jvmRoute` and `sessionIdLength`.